# How to hire a senior developer when no interviewer has that expertise?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, hiring-process

I work for a small company that has a very small development team. Before I joined the company was just the one senior developer who has been at the company for almost 10 years and designed and built the website. The website is business critical and it is how we make 99% of our income. I am a junior developer fresh out of college and this is my first job. I have fit in well and enjoy the work. Today I found out that the senior developer will be leaving in two weeks which has put me in the drivers seat of essentially everything from developing our new site and making sure the old one continues to work, to controlling the AWS server, local server, exchange server and a bunch of other things that I am not sure how to handle all on my own.

The owner and I have of course started discussing how we are going to replace the senior developer and since I am the only one who knows anything about development I am going to be conducting the interviews and looking at candidates. I feel like I am not even remotely qualified for the position that I have been put in. How do I go about conducting a technical interview when I myself am still learning not just our system but what it means to be a developer? I am hoping that we can fill the position before the senior developers last day but I want to be prepared for the likelihood that it will not happen since the pay at this company is pretty far below the averages for our area and many senior software developers wont want to take this sort of pay.

Comment: Do you have an HR department or do you work with a recruitment company (or something else)?

Comment: No HR department. All I know is how I was hired which was through craigslist. I knew the job was low paying for the work I do but took it cause I am still living at home and just wanted the experience.

Comment: Duplicate?  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12901/325

Comment: Hi Source41! Like Monica said, this is the same as the linked question - if there are details which make your situation different, go ahead and [edit] your question to make it clear how your situation is different.

Comment: Paul Graham would say [you just can't.](http://www.paulgraham.com/gh.html)

Comment: Using a management consultant or third-party recruiting firm is also likely to just waste your firm's money and time -- those places tend to drag things out depending on how they are paid with no guarantee that their criteria will really select someone you need for the role and job duties.

Answer (score 4):

There are many management consultants around who are 'engineering managers for hire'. Amongst other roles, they can assist in hiring. Good ones are very clear about getting the job of putting themselves out of a job by hiring someone permanent.

You and the owner are probably qualified to evaluate such a consultant; you can ask hard questions and check references without fear of a techno-snow job.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why can't you start the interviews while the senior developer is still around, and presumably available to back you up? Why do you have to wait until he totally takes off before you start the interviews?
2. If you are by yourself, then have yourself two rounds of interviews. In the first round of interviews: explain to the interviews what the firm wants done - the senior developer should have filled you in on that, right? And ask the candidates how they intend to get it done. Basically, the first round of interviews is for you to get educated by the candidates. Have you have some sort of a fix on what the most likely answers are, schedule a second round of interviews using questions derived from answers given by the strongest candidates in the first round, make your selection from there and hope for the best. You are quick to hire, but you'll have to be quicker to fire if they don't perform up to expectations.
3. Decide what your criteria are for selecting from the candidates. I suggest that while technical expertise is important, the candidate's ability to communicate effectively with you is even more important. Because you also want the candidate to be able to train you and bring you to senior level. Preferably fast. A candidate who is technically super proficient but can't communicate worth a damn as to what he is up to is not as appropriate for you as a candidate who is somewhat less technically proficient but whose communication skills are good enough that he can train you.
4. Have the senior developer write down a series of questions to ask and his answers to the questions before he takes off, if it's impossible to schedule any kind of interviews before he takes off.
5. @gnasher729 comments that "As a senior developer, if I left the company on good terms I might very well be persuaded to help out doing some interviews. Or I might not, but asking the leaving developer could be the simplest solution."

Comment: I am hoping that we can get some interviews setup before the senior developer leaves but I just want to be prepared. Your suggestions are very helpful as to how to get setup with some questions for the interview.

Comment: @Source41 Thanks for getting back to me - I added to my answer because you just gave me an idea :)

Comment: Items 2 and 3 are exactly the sorts of things that can't be done well without an experienced developer guiding them.

Comment: @EMS On item 3, the OP is perfectly capable of deciding on their own whether the candidate can talk to them and make themselves understood. Item 2 is a "best effort" from the developer:one round to get a feel for what the solutions could be like and a second round to pick the brains of the strongest candidates and have them compared the solution alternatives. The OP is not necessarily looking for the "best"candidate but a candidate who combines technical ability, soundness of judgement and communicates most effectively with the OP. If the "best" candidate is accidentally passed over, so be it.

Comment: As a senior developer, if I left the company on good terms I might very well be persuaded to help out doing some interviews. Or I might not, but asking the leaving developer could be the simplest solution. Of course, it's not a solution in the general case. Like a company hiring their very first developer.

Comment: @gnasher729 Good idea. I'll edit it into my answer, giving you full credit, of course :)

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan If you don't already have excellent taste in programming design and have a good understanding, then the space of topics for which it is possible for the candidate to make them clear in your mind is necessarily too small for the job (unless you want to hire a developer and not worry about their development skill). If *you* (as a non-developer) decide they can speak well, you might actually be wrong because you don't understand the really difficult stuff that you most need them to speak well about to other technical people. This is Paul Graham's argument in "Great Hackers."

Comment: And in this case I use the idea of "non-developer" and "very junior developer" interchangeably because for all practical purposes in an interview setting like this, that assumption would hold.

Comment: @EMS The OP is admittedly very inexperienced but the OP's the best that the firm has, absent the senior developer - The firm has to do what they can with what they have - Are you trying to force an optimal answer into a suboptimal situation? As for your other concern that the firm might hire a developer who can't talk to other technical people, I'll point out that the only other technical people are the OP. If the developer can't talk to the OP, then to whom do you expect that the new developer talk to, given that there are only two technical people in the firm?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan I'm saying that there is a high probability that they will hire the wrong candidate because they don't have an expert to hire the expert. This is not new advice: many software icons have said the same thing. Talented people tend to clump together: if you don't already have someone awesome you have no hope to hire an awesome person. The best thing would be to try to pay the current programmer more, give the programmer more freedom, whatever, to get the current programmer to stay (at least long enough to have the current programmer help hire a back-up).

Comment: It's a situation where "doing the best they can with what they've got" is probably net detrimental to their long-term success. It's a big reason why a lot of young companies fail. Honestly, in many cases, just avoiding hiring anyone and letting the work pile up until you find some way to hire someone awesome is actually much better. It sounds counter-intuitive, but using bad, unrelated metrics (like generic "communication" skills) to hire a needed tech expert can cause the whole place to fail.

Comment: @EMS You keep arguing for the "best", even when the "best" is not available. Your argument is exactly why the "best"is the enemy of the "good". That's not a recipe for success, that's a recipe for martyrdom. I learned my trade by fighting in the trenches and dealing with reality and often enough, unpleasant reality, not by reading books with pie in the sky concepts written by management consultants and others.

Comment: I'm not saying they have to hire the best person. I'm saying they cannot even hire a minimally suitable person without themselves having good taste and experience in the very work the developer they hire needs to do.